# Most efficient way to loop through all elements in array while adding elements

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array in Google Apps Script Javascript. I'm trying to loop through all elements but one of the loop options is adding another element. So for example:

```
for (let i in arr){
  if (arr[i][0] == "good")
    arr[i].push("clear");
  else if (arr[i][0] == "add")
    arr.splice(+i+1,0,"good");
}
```

But then it's not going through the actual end of the code, I presume because "let i in arr" is getting the leght of the array once and going to that end. This is causing later issues. Should I use a while or do while loop instead? Should I declare a length value and increase it manually whenever an element gets added?

Comment: a `for` loop that uses the `arr.length` would recompute that every time

Comment: It doens't seem to be. At the end of my code I'm printing the entire array to my Google Sheet and it's printing the exact same size as the initial array. Plus all elements after the old length aren't being processed

Comment: You are using a `for..in` loop, not a `for` loop

Comment: Ah, thank you. I thought you were saying I was wrong, not suggesting a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `arr.length` in your condition and it will check against the most up-to-date array length.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i][0] == "good")
    arr[i].push("clear");
  else if (arr[i][0] == "add")
    arr.splice(+i+1,0,"good");
}
```

Comment: So just don't use the ```for (let i in arr)``` syntax. Thanks!